# mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters error when displaying data from database

Tags: php, sql

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0"><tr><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">id</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">title</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">artist</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">last</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">peak</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">woc</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">sales</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">tSales</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">activity</th><th style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">artwork</th></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">1</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">In My Feelings</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">Drake</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">1</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">1</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">1</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">120,000</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">500,000</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">assets/images/activity/new.png</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">assets/images/artwork/1.jpg</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">2</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">I Like it</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">Cardi B</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">2</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">1</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">15</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">95,000</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">650,000</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">assets/images/activity/nomove.png</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">assets/images/artwork/2.jpg</td></tr><tr><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">Girls Like You</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">Maroon 5</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">4</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">3</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">4</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">91,500</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">500,000</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">assets/images/activity/up.png</td><td style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:inherit;vertical-align:top">assets/images/artwork/3.jpg</td></tr></table>
```

I have this table and I want to echo it on my page but when I preview my code on my browser, it displays this:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\calcharts\index.php on line 35

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\calcharts\index.php on line 39

Here's the code:

```
<div class="content">

    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM singles ORDER BY sales;");

    $produceByType = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con, $result)) {
        $produceByType[ $row['title'] ][] = $row;
    }
    ?>

    <table>
    <?php
    foreach ($produceByType as $title => $produce):
    ?>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8"><?= $type ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($produce as $row): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $row['artist'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['last'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['peak'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['woc'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['sales'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['tSales'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['activity'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $row['artwork'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        endforeach;
    endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: In addition to the linked resource, you don't actually include any of the relevant code -- please include the calls to both `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_fetch_array` in your sample code.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I've been trying to but when I paste it here, it doesn't display the top part. let me fix it.

Comment: You can't just add an `i` and have `mysqli` function as `mysql_` did. Please consult the manual. Parameter 1 must be the link for procedural usage. `mysqli_fetch_array` doesn't take a link.

Comment: @user3783243 alright so how do i fix it? change mysqli to mysql ? i'm still a beginner at this and I need lots of help

Comment: The manual always tells you everything you need to know. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php `mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query` and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php `mysqli_fetch_array ( mysqli_result $result` So long version ... `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM singles ORDER BY sales;");` and `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {`

Comment: @user3783243 will do. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is just example :

```
$conn = your database connection  ;

$qry = "SELECT * FROM singles ORDER BY sales";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
  if($result->num_rows > 0){
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     echo $row;
   }
  }
```